# Scrape historical tweets based on Hashtag without Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, python-requests, hashtag

I have a webscraper that, given a hashtag, will return the tweets with that hashtag. The problem I have is that when I make a request to twitter to get the hashtags, I only receive about 20 tweets. I am using requests to make the request and grab the page source, which only contains the 20 tweets.

I believe that twitter renders the tweets only a few at a time but I wanted to know if there was a way, without using the twitter api, to get more than what is initially rendered on the page.

My current code to make the request looks like the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def find_hashtags(hashtag):
    r = requests.get('https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hashtag + '?src=hash')
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")

find_tweets('cnn')
```

Does anybody know of a workaround to this?

Comment: try using `selenium` or `selenium-requests`

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using BeautifulSoup is that it is purely for html scrapping. The first tweets are loaded automatically in the html, but the next are loaded using javascript. BeautifulSoup wont be able to access those and you will need some other library which can handle javascript loaded elements. I would suggest looking into selenium which can mimic a web user.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find to do this is to use [twitters search page](http://twitter.com/search-home) and to scrape the data from the webpage. You can get more seach data by modifying date to and date from in the search query.

Modify the parameters of the URL to produce diffrent search results. For example, appending the parameter `q=%23hashtagName` to the URL will give you tweets including the hashtag `"hashtagname"`.

https://twitter.com/search?q=%23hashtagName

Comment: Sorry for the naive question but how do I modify the search query?

Comment: @JoeyB The queries for the search are all set in the URL. You go to the Advanced search page and see how different search options affect the URL.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing which worked really well was using selenium to open the browser, and scroll the page down 'i' number of times.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re

def find_hashtags(hashtag):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hashtag + '?src=hash')
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100000)")
        time.sleep(1.5)
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient way but it does what I want!